# Ubuntu 18.04 - Brother Laser Printer - "does not accept jobs" - pending

Tags: 18.04, printing

Ubuntu 18.04 - Brother Laser Printer - "does not accept jobs" - basically it just build up printing que in pending mode. I did click on properties to get latest driver.

Strange enough it "used to print" before my last update."

I read on one page that I needed to resart cups which I did "i think"

Grateful for some guidance

Comment: Which particular printer? Installing my Brother_HL-2240D_from System Settings (i run kubuntu) just worked.

Can you see the device it if you type `lsusb`? Sometimes silly things like a bad usb cable can be a problem!

Comment: Sometimes those pending jobs will print when you reboot and sign on again.

Comment: JayEye  - The specific printer is a - HL - L2350DW

Comment: WinEunuuchs2Unix - I have reset the printer and rebooted my machine several times - Also waited up to 30 minutes or better to see if it would process. But it just says "pending."

Comment: My printer started working but I honestly don't how it happened. There is a printer dialog that keeps popping up over and over saying that a printer is being added when I boot up my machine. It would not work but I think after a software update it must have solved itself. I was giving up on it but it now is fixed.

Comment: Experiencing the same issues also with `Brother_HL_L2350DW_series` also with message:  _Does not accept jobs_  I have Ubuntu 18.04. Hope it will resolve itself automatically in the future then :)